# Не выполняется функция, добавленная в существующий класс

Tags: python, tkinter

Я только изучаю классы и у меня возникла проблема. Код в классе работает, но как я пытаюсь дополнить класс своей функцией - все работает как прежде, но функции я будто не добавлял, она просто будто не работает. Я не могу понять почему. Прошу объяснить и, возможно, поправить код, чтобы вставленная мной функция выполнялась и отображалась сетка. (Функция должна нарисовать сетку на холсте)

Неработающая часть кода помечена комментариями.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Example(Frame):
  def __init__(self, root):
      Frame.__init__(self, root)
      self.warehouse_canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, background="bisque")
      self.xsb = Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.warehouse_canvas.xview)
      self.ysb = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.warehouse_canvas.yview)
      self.warehouse_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
      self.warehouse_canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000))

      self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
      self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
      self.warehouse_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
      self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
      self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

      root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
      root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

      self.warehouse_canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.scroll_start)
      self.warehouse_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.scroll_move)

      # (ниже) неработающая часть кода, которая должна рисовать сетку:
      canvas_width = 400
      canvas_height = 400
      self.canvas_width = canvas_width
      self.canvas_height = canvas_height

  def draw_grid(root, warehouse_canvas, canvas_width, canvas_height):
      for line in range(0, canvas_width, 10):
          warehouse_canvas.create_line([(line, 0), (line, canvas_height)], fill='black', tags='grid_line_width')
      for line in range(0, canvas_width, 10):
          warehouse_canvas.create_line([(0, line), (canvas_width, line)], fill='black', tags='grid_line_height')
      # (выше) неработающая часть кода, которая должна рисовать сетку:

def scroll_start(self, event):
    self.warehouse_canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def scroll_move(self, event):
    self.warehouse_canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   Example(root).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,
                   sticky="nsew")
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выполнить метод/функцию, его надо вызвать:

```
self.draw_grid(self.warehouse_canvas, canvas_width, canvas_height)   # <----
```

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.warehouse_canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, background="bisque")
        self.xsb = Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.warehouse_canvas.xview)
        self.ysb = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.warehouse_canvas.yview)
        self.warehouse_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.warehouse_canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000))

        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.warehouse_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.warehouse_canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.scroll_start)
        self.warehouse_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.scroll_move)

        # (ниже) неработающая часть кода, которая должна рисовать сетку:
        canvas_width = 400
        canvas_height = 400
        self.canvas_width = canvas_width
        self.canvas_height = canvas_height

        self.draw_grid(self.warehouse_canvas, canvas_width, canvas_height)   # <----

    def draw_grid(root, warehouse_canvas, canvas_width, canvas_height):
        for line in range(0, canvas_width, 10):
            warehouse_canvas.create_line([(line, 0), (line, canvas_height)], fill='black', tags='grid_line_width')
        for line in range(0, canvas_width, 10):
            warehouse_canvas.create_line([(0, line), (canvas_width, line)], fill='black', tags='grid_line_height')
        # (выше) неработающая часть кода, которая должна рисовать сетку:

    def scroll_start(self, event):
        self.warehouse_canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

    def scroll_move(self, event):
        self.warehouse_canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   Example(root).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2,
                   sticky="nsew")
   root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]